# Spring Cloud AWS SQS SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory configuration for multiple @SqsListeners

Tags: spring-cloud

Is it possible to have different SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory @Beans defined and use them for different @SqsListeners?  Since the underlying number of threads depend on what the max batch size is set to in the SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory, I would want to be able to configure the property lower for some @SqsListeners that may be listening to a queue that do not receive many messages vs other @SqsListeners that listen to a queue with many messages and give more resources to those listeners.  For Example

```
@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory containerFactoryForLargeQueue(final AmazonSQSAsync amazonSqs) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setAmazonSqs(amazonSqs);
    factory.setMaxNumberOfMessages(10);
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory containerFactoryForSmallQueue(final AmazonSQSAsync amazonSqs) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setAmazonSqs(amazonSqs);
    factory.setMaxNumberOfMessages(5);
    return factory;
}
```

And then somehow configure the @SqsListener to use one or the other depending on the volume of messages it receives from its queue.